# How to get only most recent SMS to use in conversation view?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an sms conversation list. I am using this code to get a cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
```

The problem is that when I use the cursor, I get multiple messages from one contact. I am trying to get only the most recent message from all contacts so that I can show them in a recyclerview as a list of conversations.

Thanks in advance!﻿

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst(); is the first message which is last received.

Comment: The `content://sms/conversations` URI (`Telephony.Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI`) will return a summary of each conversation, with the `snippet` column being the last message in each. If you want specifically the last _received_ message, that would probably be a little more involved.

Comment: Ohhhhh okay, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the info, if you want you can copy that to an answer and I will accept it as so. Thanks again! :D @MikeM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying the `"content://sms/conversations"` URI (`Telephony.Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI`) will return a summary of each conversation, with the `"snippet"` column (`Telephony.Sms.Conversations.SNIPPET`) being the last message in each.

This query will also return with a `"msg_count"` column (`Telephony.Sms.Conversations.MESSAGE_COUNT`) - which is pretty self-explanatory - and a `"thread_id"` column (`Telephony.Sms.Conversations.THREAD_ID`), which can be used to retrieve a complete conversation, by querying with that ID appended to the conversations URI. For example:

```
String threadId = ...
Uri convoUri = Telephony.Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI
               .buildUpon().appendPath(threadId).build();
```

Do note that these queries will return only SMS messages. If you want MMS as well, `Telephony.Mms` and `Telephony.MmsSms` have similar URIs.